# Format Date with OpenFeign

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper, openfeign

My Feign client is defined as follow :

```
@FeignClient(name = "${feign.name}",url = "${feign.url}",
        configuration = {DateFormatConfiguration.class})
public interface MyFeignClient {

@GetMapping(value = "/test")
    ResponseEntity<MyResponse> getResponse(@RequestParam(value = "date") Date date);

}
```

Where :

```
 class DateFormatConfiguration {
    
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Bean
    public FeignFormatterRegistrar dateFeignFormatterRegistrar() {
        return formatterRegistry -> formatterRegistry.addFormatter(new Formatter<Date>() {
            @Override
            public Date parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
                return df.parse(text);
            }
            @Override
            public String print(Date object, Locale locale) {
                return df.format(object);
            }
        });
    }
   }
```

However when I run this test :

```
@Test
public void test(){
    Date date= new GregorianCalendar(2000, 12, 31).getTime();
    myFeignClient.getResponse(date);
}
```

the request is sent into this format :

> ```
> ---> GET https:xxx/test?date=Wed%20Jan%2031%2000%3A00%3A00%20EST%202001
> ```

What I'm trying to have is :

> ```
> ---> GET https:xxx/test?date=2000-12-31
> ```

Where the date is formatter as I need.

I've tried also this solution, but not working neither:

```
class DateFormatConfiguration {
        
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    
        @Bean
        public JacksonEncoder feignEncoder() {
            return new JacksonEncoder(customObjectMapper());
        }
    
        @Bean
        public JacksonDecoder feignDecoder() {
            return new JacksonDecoder(customObjectMapper());
        }
    
        private ObjectMapper customObjectMapper(){
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.setDateFormat(df);
            return objectMapper;
        }
       }
```

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score -1):

You should consider trying replace necessary lines with something like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");    
LocalDate date= LocalDate.ofInstant(new GregorianCalendar(2000, 12, 31).getTime().toInstant(), ZoneId.of(TimeZone.getDefault().getID()));
String dateFormatted = date.format(dtf);
```

Comment: it is a Date not a LocalDate, and my issue is with Feign

Comment: no it's not. you're just supplying malformed date from elsewhere and trying to set feign up to parse it the way you want. do try to apply the lines above in test method without any unnecessary configurations

Comment: OP want to serialise the Date object in Feign with format he wants. You try to replace the test instead of answering the question.